# Excel/VBA Merge columns sequentially from all tabs by column name

Tags: vba, excel

I need to merge certain columns by header from each excel workbook tab into one.

I have 52 tabs, each with a different number of columns, but the 6 columns i need all have the same header.  I need to extract each of these columns and place them sequentially so 52 tabs would look like this for example

[image: Excel example]

but if I want to select just 'Column1' from each tab and display sequentially like this

[image: Excel Merged Example]

How would I do this ? I've been able to find some examples on SO but none that fit this case, and so far I've been unable to piece together a solution on my own.  Any help would be very much appreciated!

*EDIT*

This is what I currently have, however this is also printing the header as well

```
Sub Combine()

Dim J As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add
Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"
Sheets(2).Activate

For J = 2 To Sheets.Count
    Sheets(J).Activate
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set rng1 = Range(Range("A1:Z1").Find("Customer"), Range("A1:Z1").Find("Customer").End(xlDown))
    rng1.Select
    rng1.CurrentRegion.Select
    'Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
    rng1.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
    rng1.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)

Next

Sheets(1).Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: I think that you could build a loop that open each sheet and each file you need. Then you look for a column with specifica header and copy it into a new file. Try with macro recorder and the parametrize the code. If you'll find specific problem ask here.

Comment: please post what you have so we can work with that.

Comment: Thanks for that @Nicolaesse  I've just added an edit showing progress so far.  If I could figure out why the header is also included Id be a lot of the way there.  Thanks.